# How to configure django rest framework DjangoFilterBackend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I added the following to settings:

```
'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',),
```

Now when I try to access the browsable api I get the following error:

```
filter_instance = cls(request.query_params, queryset=queryset)<br>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I have tried adding the following to my serializer:

```
filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
filter_fields = ('featured',)
```

I can still hit the endpoint using curl without any issues though.

Comment: Can you give an example of the URL you are trying to retrieve? For example `/myurl/?featured=1`

Comment: Example would be /myurl/ . I can curl the same endpoint but if I try to access it in the browsable view I receive that error.

Comment: Updating to django rest framework 3.3.3 fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to update django rest framework, I had a similar issue and it has been fixed by an update.